# Difference between a shared memory based pipe , in Posix vs System V?

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, shared-memory

As part of my homework project I had to implement a library that implements a pipe using shared memory. Both the anonymous and named pipe .

I chose the `Posix` implementation , meaning , I used the following calls :

```
mmap()
shm_open()
ftruncate()
shm_unlink()

For semaphores and synchronization 

sem_init()
sem_getvalue()
sem_wait()
sem_post()
```

(I might forgot one or two calls)

My TA told me that he prefers that I'd implement that library with `System V` version ,
however since I'm in the middle of my exams , I have no extra time to do that (would take a least a week , I guess) .

My questions are :

1. What's is the difference between a pipe that's implemented in Posix vs a pipe that's implemented in System-V ?
2. What calls would I need for implementing the above library using the `Sys V` version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to question (1) - there should be no differences between a `Posix` implementation of a pipe and a `System V` implementation of a pipe - if you're implementing a library with a set of routines, then the user should not see any difference between the two implementations.

For the developer, the shared memory calls that are used for `System V` are: [`shmget`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/shmget%282%29) to create [`shmat`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/shmat%282%29) to access and [`shmctl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/shmctl.html) to destroy (`shmdt` is used to unmap the shared memory segment from the current process).

You use a call to [`ftok`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/ftok%283%29) which converts a filename into the key that you will use.

Note that the key is the magic *uniquification* item that distinguishes between the different shared memory/semaphore items.

For getting semaphores you use [`semget`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/semget%282%29), to lock and unlock you use [`semop`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/semop%282%29) and to destroy it you use [`semctl`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/semctl%282%29).

System V semaphores and shared memory segments can survive beyond the execution of a program - i.e. if the program terminates without destroying them, then they will remain in the system until they are destroyed or recreated either programmatically, or using [`ipcrm`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_ipcrm.htm)